Flutter WidgetExtension leads to build error 'is unavailable in application extensions'
I added the home widget extension to my Flutter app and use the home_widget package. Therefore I extended the Podfile to use interactive widgets in iOS:
target 'AllTasksWidgetExtension' do
   use_frameworks!
   use_modular_headers!

   pod 'home_widget', :path => '.symlinks/plugins/home_widget/ios'
  end 

This lead to the following build error:

Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): 'addApplicationDelegate' is unavailable in application extensions for iOS: Disallowed in plugins used in app extensions.
/Users/myUser/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/app_links-6.3.2/ios/Classes/SwiftAppLinksPlugin.swift:24:14


Any solution about this?
